# SQL Server contained database - get password hash

Tags: sql-server

I have a contained database with users authenticated in the database only (i.e. SQL user with password).  What I am looking to do is the "uncontain" the database.  Before I can change alter the database to containment 'NONE', I must remove all contained users.  What I really want to do is create a SQL login for the user retaining the same password.

With a server login, I can use LOGINPROPERTY('myusername', 'PasswordHash') to get the password hash.  For a SQL user with password (a contained user), this returns null.  Where can I get the password hash for a contained user?

Comment: Gosh putting sql server and your actual question in google returns might good results. https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+password+hash+for+a+contained+user&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 2):

This article has the answer http://sqlblog.com/blogs/argenis_fernandez/archive/2014/07/28/scripting-out-contained-database-users.aspx

The article states that for contained database users, there is (currently) no method of obtaining SID or password hashes without connecting to the DAC (Dedicated Administrator Connection).  Once you establish a DAC connection, the following query will give you the password hash:

```
SELECT password FROM sys.sysowners WHERE name = 'ContainedUser'
```

For information on how to connect get a DAC with SSMS, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I was just looking for this.. Saved me some time, Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the [sp_help_revlogin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992) stored procedure?

Comment: This stored procedure does not find the login.  The reason is that  contained users do not have a login on the instance and therefore are not in sys.server_principals.