# Is it possible to copy a contained user with password using SMO?

Tags: sql-server, smo

I am using SMO to create a copy of a database for testing. The database I am copying is a partially contained database with a contained user (i.e. the user was created using a CREATE USER x WITH PASSWORD = 'y' type of statement).

All is well except that the password for the contained user in the target database is not the same as in the source database.

The SMO code I am using is:

```
var transfer = new Transfer(sourceDatabase)
{
    DestinationServer = destinationServerName,
    DestinationDatabase = destinationDatabaseName,
    CopyAllSchemas = true,
    CopyAllRoles = true,
    CopyAllUsers = true,
    CopyAllDatabaseTriggers = true,
    CopyAllDefaults = true,
    CopyData = false,
    Options =
    {
        DriAll = true,
        Triggers = true,
        ScriptOwner = true,
        Permissions = true,
    }
}

transfer.TransferData();
```

I can run a query to set the password explicitly following the copy, and I believe it may be possible to copy the password in its hashed form (as mentioned in [SQL Server contained database - get password hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137397)). However, I was wondering if there was some option that I have overlooked that allows me to do this using options associated with the SMO `Transfer` or related classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server contained database - get password hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137397/sql-server-contained-database-get-password-hash)

Comment: Not a duplicate as I am asking if this can be performed using the SMO classes.